# VBA excel. How to get access to chart scale by chart name?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

It seems to be simple but can’t figure out how to operate wiht charts by name.
For example this code works fine:

```vb
Sub scale_chart()
    Dim chart_name As String
    chart_name = "Chart 3"
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chart_name).Select
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = 800000
    End With
End Sub
```

But below codes provide "Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support proprty or method"

```vb
Sub scale_chart()
    Dim chart_name As String
    chart_name = "Chart 3"
    With ActiveSheet.Charts(chart_name).Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = 800000
    End With
End Sub
```

and

```vb
Sub scale_chart()
    Dim chart_name As String
    chart_name = "Chart 3"
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chart_name).Charts.Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = 800000
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm trying to avoid .select as it recomended here
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
but still need more knowledges.
Would be appreciated if someone point me what I'm doing wrong :)
p.s.: it's VBA Excel 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try,

Sub scale_chart()
    Dim chart_name As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim objCht As ChartObject
    Dim Cht As Chart
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    
    chart_name = "Chart 3"
    Set objCht = Ws.ChartObjects(chart_name)
    Set Cht = objCht.Chart
    With Cht.Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = 800000
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is more important I've found the mistake! "With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chart_name).Charts.Axes(xlValue)" should be "With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chart_name).Chart.Axes(xlValue)"